# Calculating bank angle between two objects

Tags: vector, unity-game-engine

I have a drone following a path for movement.  That is, it doesn't use a rigidbody so I don't have access to velocity or magnitude and such.  It follows the path just fine, but I would like to add banking to it when it turns left or right.  I use a dummy object in front of the drone, thinking I could calculate the bank/tilt amount using the transform vectors from the two objects.

I've been working on this for days as I don't have a lot of math skills.  Basically I've been copying pieces of code trying to get things to work.  Nothing I do works to make the drone bank.  The following code manages to spin (not bank).

```
    // Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.identity;
    Vector3 dir = (dummyObject.transform.position - this.transform.position).normalized;
    float angle = Vector3.Angle( dir, transform.up );

    float rollAngle = CalculateRollAngle(angle);
    rotation.SetLookRotation(dir, transform.right);// + rollIntensity * smoothRoll * right);
    rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, rollAngle));
    transform.rotation = rotation;
}

/// <summary>
/// Calculates Roll and smoothes it (to compensates for non C2 continuous control points algorithm) /// </summary>
/// <returns>The roll angle.</returns>
/// <param name="rollFactor">Roll factor.</param>
float CalculateRollAngle(float rollFactor)
{
    smoothRoll = Mathf.Lerp(smoothRoll, rollFactor, rollSmoothing * Time.deltaTime);
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(1, smoothRoll * rollIntensity);
    angle *= Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    angle -= 90;

    TurnRollAngle = angle;

    angle += RollOffset;
    return angle;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want as of banking? The drone is tilting left and right (like a boat) in a rhythm? Or when it turn left, tilt left, then back to straight when going straight again, or....?

Comment: Hi thanks, I want went he drone turns left that it banks left and when turn turn right that it banks accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have waypoints the drone is following, you should figure out the angle between the last two (i.e. your "now-facing" and "will be facing" directions). The easy way is to use [Vector2.Angle](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Angle.html).
I would use this angle to determine the amount I'll tilt the drone's body: the sharper the turn, the harder the banking. I would use a ratio value (*public initially so I can manipulate it from the editor*).
 
Next, instead of doing any math I would rely on the engine to do the rotation for me - so I would go for [Transform.Rotate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) function.
In case banking can go too high and look silly, I would set a maximum for that and [Clamp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) my calculated banking angle between zero and max.
Without knowing exactly what you do and how, it's not easy to give perfect code, but for a better understand of the above, here's some (untested, i.e. pseudo) code for the solution I visualize:

```
public float turnSpeed = 7.0f; //the drone will "rotate toward the new waypoint" by this speed

//bankSpeed+turnBankRatio must be two times "faster" (and/or smaller degree) than turning, see details in 'EDIT' as of why:
public float bankSpeed = 14.0f; //banking speed
public float turnBankRatio = .5f; //90 degree turn == 45 degree banking


private float turnAngle = 0.0f; //this is the 'x' degree turning angle we'll "Lerp"
private float turnAngleABS = 0.0f; //same as turnAngle but it's an absolute value. Storing to avoid Mathf.Abs() in Update()!
private float bankAngle = 0.0f; //banking degree
private  bool isTurning = false; //are we turning right now?

//when the action is fired for the drone it should go for the next waypoint, call this guy
private void TurningTrigger() {
   //remove this line after testing, it's some extra safety
   if (isTurning) { Debug.LogError("oups! must not be possible!"); return; }
   Vector2 droneOLD2DAngle = GetGO2DPos(transform.position);
   //do the code you do for the turning/rotation of drone here!
   //or use the next waypoint's .position as the new angle if you are OK
   //with the snippet doing the turning for you along with banking. then:
   Vector2 droneNEW2DAngle = GetGO2DPos(transform.position);
   turnAngle    = Vector2.Angle(droneOLD2DAngle, droneNEW2DAngle); //turn degree
   turnAngleABS = Mathf.Abs(turnAngle); //avoiding Mathf.Abs() in Update()
   bankAngle    = turnAngle * turnBankRatio; //bank angle
   //you can remove this after testing. This is to make sure banking can
   //do a full run before the drone hits the next waypoint!
   if ((turnAngle * turnSpeed) < (bankAngle * bankSpeed)) {
       Debug.LogError("Banking degree too high, or banking speed too low to complete maneuver!");
   }
   //you can clamp or set turnAngle based on a min/max here
   isTurning = true; //all values were set, turning and banking can start!
}

//get 2D position of a GO (simplified)
private Vector2 GetGO2DPos(Vector3 worldPos) {
    return new Vector2(worldPos.x, worldPos.z);
}

private void Update() {
    if (isTurning) {
         //assuming the drone is banking to the "side" and "side" only
         transform.Rotate(0, 0, bankAngle * time.deltaTime * bankSpeed, Space.Self); //banking
         //if the drone is facing the next waypoint already, set
         //isTurning to false
    } else if (turnAngleABS > 0.0f) {
         //reset back to original position (with same speed as above)
         //at least "normal speed" is a must, otherwise drone might hit the
         //next waypoint before the banking reset can finish!
         float bankAngle_delta = bankAngle * time.deltaTime * bankSpeed;
         transform.Rotate(0, 0, -1 * bankAngle_delta, Space.Self);
         turnAngleABS -= (bankAngle_delta > 0.0f) ? bankAngle_delta : -1 * bankAngle_delta;
    }
    //the banking was probably not set back to exactly 0, as time.deltaTime
    //is not a fixed value. if this happened and looks ugly, reset
    //drone's "z" to Quaternion.identity.z. if it also looks ugly,
    //you need to test if you don't """over bank""" in the above code
    //by comparing bankAngle_delta + 'calculated banking angle' against
    //the identity.z value, and reset bankAngle_delta if it's too high/low.
    //when you are done, your turning animation is over, so:
}
```

Again, this code might not perfectly fit your needs (or compile :P), so focus on the idea and the approach, not the code itself. Sorry for not being able right now to put something together and test myself - but I hope I helped. Cheers!

**EDIT:** Instead of a wall of text I tried to answer your question in code (still not perfect, but goal is not doing the job, but to help with some snippets and ideas :)
So. Basically, what you have is a distance and "angle" between two waypoints. This distance and your drone's flight/walk/whatever speed (which I don't know) is the **maximum** amount of time available for:

   **1.** Turning, so the drone will face in the new direction

   **2.** Banking to the side, and back to zero/"normal"

As there's two times more action on banking side, it either has to be done faster (`bankSpeed`), or in a smaller angle (`turnBankRatio`), or both, depending on what looks nice and feels real, what your preference is, etc. So it's 100% subjective. It's also your call if the drone turns+banks quickly and approaches toward the next waypoint, or does things in slow pace and turns just a little if has a lot of time/distance and does things fast only if it has to.
As of `isTurning`:
You set it to true when the drone reached a waypoint and heads out to the next one **AND** the variables to (turn and) bank were set properly. When you set it to false? It's up to you, but the goal is to do so when the maneuver is finished (this was buggy in the snippet the first time as this "optimal status" was not possible to ever be reached) so he drone can "reset banking".
For further details on what's going on, see code comments.
Again, this is just a snippet to support you with a possible solution for your problem. Give it some time and understand what's going on. It really is easy, you just need some time to cope ;)
Hope this helps! Enjoy and cheers! :)

Comment: Thanks Mark, pseudo works for me so thanks.  Will try this out and make adjustments (if any) to see if I can get something working.

Comment: This works great and I only had to fix the time.deltaTime for it to compile.  The problem is when the event is fired to start the rotation, isTurning is set to true and starts the drone banking, but it continues banking until the next waypoint tells it to bank.  isTurning never gets to false (in order to reset the drone).  I tried placing isTurning to false just after it launches the first transform.Rotate, but that kills the banking all together; obviously not where it needs to be set.  So do you know at what point this should be set so that the current bank stops? :)  thanks

Comment: @Valerie Oh yes, that indeed works like that (developed a bug for you :) as the time is divided up that way. Means: banking ANGLE is half the turn speed, but banking SPEED is equals it - as it uses Time.deltaTime, just like the code for turning does. What you need to add is speed. So something like "turnAngle * time.deltaTime * [speed faster than the speed by which you approach the next waypoint]", so to speak. Then play around with these numbers to make it look good in your game and fit your needs

Comment: thanks for the help.  I've re-read your comment and if I understand correctly, you say adding a speed variable will help reset the drone once a bank has been completed.  I'm assuming this means that when the speed gets to a certain level, then I set isTurning to false; which will then stop the banking for the current wp.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Valerie answer updated, see snippet + text after the EDIT label ;)

Comment: Okay thanks so much.  I will keep working with the new snippets.  Love that you provided code snippets and comments to help, rather that just providing a solution! :)

Comment: @Valerie SO answer guys are here to help, not for doing the job of someone else. I would btw if that was the easier :) For Unity it's not possible in most cases as problems tend to be specific to a particular game, which is unique. Like your case. I don't know what drones you have, how they move, what's the game's overall impression and what it is about so... All I can do is give a generic approach on the base issue and let the coder do the job from there. I'm happy if I could help. If the above is a solution for you, glad if you vote and/or accept the answer. Cheers.